# Set Time out by passing a parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, timeout

i'm currently have a problem by using the SetTimeOut function.

The thing is that i need to use it by passing a parameter, but it didn't work...
Here is the code :

```
function RSSChecker(dMObject)
{
    if (dMObject) 
    {
        alert('Refresh');
        window.setTimeout(RSSChecker(dMObject), 10000);
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: do you have RSSChecker('blabla'); anywhere?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp also check this page should refresh your memory abit :)

Comment: is that your intention, to call this function recursively?

Comment: @Val - pls don't cite w3schools.com - their timing examples are rubbish

Comment: It is good enough for a beginner so he should use his intuition to learn more about it, or google :)

Comment: it's not good enough for a beginner - it teaches very bad habits like using a string instead of a function as the first parameter for `setTimeout`.

Comment: Woohoo the first w3fools reference I've seen on SO (that wasn't mine)! +1000

Comment: You might like the **right** version of setTimeout (according to Mozilla): https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout (notice the optional `param1, param2, ...`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another approach would be to wrap the inner call in an anonymous function that invokes your function. So that you have:-

```
window.setTimeout(function() { RSSChecker(dmObject); }, 10000);
```

Comment: This won't keep the right variable in the right scope if the setTimeout is executed within a loop. (Maybe it's not in which case I'll shut up `=)`.)

Comment: Yep, there would be issues with the dmObject closure scope in that case, but the example code doesn't have a loop so it works here. However, if there was a loop, wrapping the window.setTimeout in another anonymous function would do the trick, but that would over-complicate this code IMO

Comment: Yup. All true. Agreed. See the +2?

Comment: Thanks! I got bitten recently by the 'closure in a loop' thing so it doesn't do any harm to bring it up